# Android: How to make this "tab switcher"

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

im trying to make a "Tab switcher" like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5DMW.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIGHP.png

Im actually using Buttons for the Tabs, and Layouts for the Views. I set Layout's Visibility to GONE when its unactive, and to VISIBLE when i press the Tab Button. It's okey? Is there a better way to do this?

I dont know if i should use Fragments inside the Layout and load Tabs from a different activity, or just make the design of tab in the Layout and the same activity.

I will show you some code, so you can understand me:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="ACTIVITY ONE"
        android:id="@+id/btnActivity1"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layActivity1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.android.tests.fragments.tab1"
            android:id="@+id/fraActivity1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/layout_tab1" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="ACTIVITY TWO"
        android:id="@+id/btnActivity2"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_normal"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layActivity2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:id="@+id/btnNEXT"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity1, i use Fragment, in Activity2, i dont. What is the correct way?

The code is something like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnActivity1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnActivity1);
        Button btnActivity2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnActivity2);
        final FrameLayout layActivity1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.layActivity1);
        final LinearLayout layActivity2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layActivity2);

        btnActivity1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layActivity1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layActivity2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        btnActivity2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                layActivity1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layActivity2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I dont know if i have to use "extends Activity" or "FragmentActivity". Every comment will be helpful.

Sorry for bad english, i hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Expandable Layout:
https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout

Comment: Looks nice. I like the animation. But can i modify the header text programatically? Because i want to show the actual value of the field: look how "John" appear in the 2nd image of the original post.

Comment: You can see in sample, change String in Header String[]. Then setAdapter again or notifidatasetchange